# How to generate filename for an image that have been saved from clipboard? VisualBasic

Tags: vb.net, filenames, clipboard

I just started to to learn VB, and I wanted to create a program which saves my clipboard (ProntScreen).
I've succeed there, but I want to generate filename for those images, so I can take lot of them into the same folder without changing the source code.

Here is my code:

```
    Public Class Form1
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If Not System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.GetDataObject() Is Nothing Then
        Dim oDataObj As IDataObject = System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.GetDataObject()
        If oDataObj.GetDataPresent(System.Windows.Forms.DataFormats.Bitmap) Then
            Dim oImgObj As System.Drawing.Image = oDataObj.GetData(DataFormats.Bitmap, True)
            'To Save as Bitmap
            'oImgObj.Save("c:\Test.bmp", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp)
            'To Save as Jpeg
            oImgObj.Save("d:\Test\test.jpeg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
            'To Save as Gif
            'oImgObj.Save("c:\Test.gif", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif)
        End If
    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

As you can see the image is saved to a fix location which is `D:\Test\Test.jpeg`
I want to generate the filename (test.jpeg). Maybe the current time would be cool like 114512 or something like that

Comment: You can generate current timestamp + random number and use it in place of test.jpg. That will solve your problem.

Comment: So could you tell me how would the "d:\Test\test.jpeg" part look like? Because if I put anything inside the string, that will create the file like that. :o

Comment: I am not a VB guy. I use C#. I can give you details if you can write the code. Writing it in answer in a min

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not a VB person, i work on C# but let me give it a shot. Declare a `System.DateTime` variable and store current datetime in that. Then declare another `String` variable, lets call it **imagePath**. In the string variable construct the path by **joining the folder path(d:\Test\", timestand, image extention(.jpeg)**. Finally use this imagePath variable in .Save methond to pass the path and name. Below is the code for this, as i told **this is my first time I am even trying VB code. There can be mistakes in the code but the logic remains the same, please change the code if there are any mistakes.**

```
Dim timeStamp As System.DateTime
timeStamp = Now;

Dim imagePath as String
imagePath = "d:\Test\" + timeStamp + ".jpeg";

oImgObj.Save(imagePath, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
```

Comment: Yes, it's partially working, the only problem is that the hour:minute:seconds format is seperated with :, and creating files is not allowed... So I have to remove all kind if space and symbls. Or just replace them with '-' for example. Thank you by the way, I'm almost done :)

Comment: hmm.... i guess i missed that. My bad. You can format the date as required using Format function. Check this link here http://www.vbtutor.net/vb2008/vb2008_lesson16.html

Comment: And plz mark as answer if it helps and an upvote will be amazing ;)